# SQL WHERE clause performance degradation

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have a query that I am working on and it is displaying performance issues that I would not have expected. Here is the query so far.

```
INSERT INTO @Bridge (PolicyNumber, ProducerCode, BridgeDate, EffectiveDate, FirstName, LastName, LicenseNumber, BirthDate, Address, City, State, ZipCode)
SELECT     tab.col.value('@PolicyNumber', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS PolicyNumber,
           tab.col.value('@ProducerCode','VARCHAR(10)') as ProducerCode,
           tab.col.value('@BridgeDate','DATETIME') AS BridgeDate,
           tab.col.value('@EffectiveDate', 'DATETIME') as EffectiveDate,
           tab.col.value('@FirstName', 'VARCHAR(200)') as FirstName,
           tab.col.value('@LastName', 'VARCHAR(200)') as LastName,
           CASE 
              WHEN tab.col.value('@LicenseNumber','VARCHAR(50)') LIKE '%0000%' THEN NULL
              WHEN tab.col.value('@LicenseNumber','VARCHAR(50)') LIKE '%1111%' THEN NULL
              WHEN tab.col.value('@LicenseNumber','VARCHAR(50)') LIKE '%2222%' THEN NULL
              WHEN tab.col.value('@LicenseNumber','VARCHAR(50)') LIKE '%3333%' THEN NULL
              WHEN tab.col.value('@LicenseNumber','VARCHAR(50)') LIKE '%4444%' THEN NULL
              WHEN tab.col.value('@LicenseNumber','VARCHAR(50)') LIKE '%5555%' THEN NULL
              WHEN tab.col.value('@LicenseNumber','VARCHAR(50)') LIKE '%6666%' THEN NULL
              WHEN tab.col.value('@LicenseNumber','VARCHAR(50)') LIKE '%7777%' THEN NULL
              WHEN tab.col.value('@LicenseNumber','VARCHAR(50)') LIKE '%8888%' THEN NULL
              WHEN tab.col.value('@LicenseNumber','VARCHAR(50)') LIKE '%9999%' THEN NULL
              ELSE tab.col.value('@LicenseNumber','VARCHAR(50)')
           END as LicenseNumber,
           tab.col.value('@BirthDate','DATETIME') as BirthDate,
           REPLACE(tab.col.value('@Address1','VARCHAR(300)'), ' APT ',' #') as Address1,
           tab.col.value('@City','VARCHAR(300)') as City,
           tab.col.value('@State','VARCHAR(5)') as State,
           tab.col.value('@ZipCode','VARCHAR(10)') as Zip
FROM       @xml.nodes('//rows/datarow') as tab(col)

SELECT     B.PolicyNumber, 
           B.ProducerCode, 
           B.BridgeDate,
           B.EffectiveDate,
           H.current_policy,
           H.cancel_date,
           H.first_eff_date,
           H.display_address,
           H.city,
           H.state,
           H.zip
FROM       @Bridge B
LEFT JOIN  (
SELECT     P.policy_id,
           P.current_policy,
           CASE 
              WHEN A.pobox <> '' THEN 'PO BOX ' + REPLACE(A.pobox,'PO BOX ','')
              ELSE RTRIM(A.house_num + ' ' + A.street_name + ' ' + CASE
                                                                      WHEN A.apt_num = '' THEN ''
                                                                      ELSE '#' + A.apt_num
                                                                    END)
           END as display_address,
           A.pobox,
           A.house_num,
           A.street_name,
           A.apt_num,
           A.city,
           MAX(A.policyimage_num) as policimage_num, --this is just to limit the results to the most recent
           S.state,
           A.zip,
           P.first_eff_date,
           P.cancel_date
FROM       Diamond.dbo.Policy P WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN  Diamond.dbo.Address A WITH (NOLOCK)
ON         P.policy_id = A.policy_id
AND        A.nameaddresssource_id = 3
LEFT JOIN  Diamond.dbo.State S WITH (NOLOCK)
ON         A.state_id = S.state_id
WHERE      A.state_id IS NOT NULL
AND        P.current_policy NOT IN (SELECT PolicyNumber FROM @Bridge)
GROUP BY   P.policy_id,
           P.current_policy,
           P.cancel_date,
           P.first_eff_date,
           A.pobox,
           A.house_num,
           A.street_name,
           A.apt_num,
           A.city,
           S.state,
           A.zip) AS H
ON         B.Address = H.display_address
AND        B.State = H.state
AND        B.City = H.city
AND        SUBSTRING(B.ZipCode,1,5) = SUBSTRING(H.Zip,1,5)
AND        B.PolicyNumber != H.current_policy
WHERE      H.current_policy IS NOT NULL
```

This query, run by itself, finishes in about 1:30 seconds. But if I add the following to the WHERE clause

```
AND       B.EffectiveDate != H.first_eff_date
```

Suddenly the query takes far longer to return results. (We are at over 15 minutes and still going while I am writing this) I would think that simply having a clause to weed out a few additional rows wouldn't have such a drastic effect, but apparently it does. I how to get around it, I am just curious if anyone has any ideas as to why it has this effect?

Comment: Have you looked at the actual execution plans for the two queries? Those should tell you what is happening with that extra condition - what kind of impact it has on the execution of the query. Maybe that can help you pinpoint something that would help speed things up again.

Comment: How many rows are in your (unindexed) table variable `@Bridge`?  A indexed table might be the _(sorry)_ key.

Comment: Are you trying to filter out records on the basis of `AND        A.nameaddresssource_id = 3`. It is important to understand behaviour of query when using LEFT JOIN and using AND in the join condition. If you are sure that you have placed joins correctly then we can looks at improving the query without changing any conditions. Check this http://techpint.com/programming/how-sql-joins-works. Also can you give estimated no of rows in each table on which you are placing a join. can you put an execution plan of the query

Comment: Your left outer join against `H` becomes an inner join when you say `WHERE H.<anything>` instead of adding that clause to the join criteria... so why is it a left outer join at all?

Comment: @user92546, About 300 Rows in the Bridge table

Comment: @Shantanu Gupta, yes, I am joining them correctly for what I am trying to achieve. I am not trying to limit the overall result set but to limit the matches in the join.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I tend to favor left joins. In this instance, I do see your logic that it is effectively resulting in an inner join, but does that imply a difference in execution time?

Comment: @Goblyn27 I don't understand your question. You're saying you "favor" left joins, do you mean even when you are attempting to get an inner join? WHY? About execution time, I'm not sure, it is *possible* that a different plan will be used when you change the syntax of the query but not really the underlying meaning. SQL Server is relatively good at retrieving what you meant, not what you said, but it's not perfect. If you're after an inner join, why isn't it written that way?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, what happens is that by default I tend to write joins as outer joins. Usually, for the data that I am working with, I don't have true inner join situations, since the left side is almost always relevant for me whether or not there is a match on the right side. So when I am writing a query, and I tend to write them piece by piece and test each iteration to see how the results are effected by each change, I tend to write left joins out of habit and when its time to limit the results to just left-right matches, by then it may not occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

Without having a hands on I can only guess at this, but here are some places I think you can tidy up and probably shave off run time.

1, You duplicate the effort required to make sure policy numbers don't match. Pick one of the two you have, not both. I would suggest trying both see which is faster.

i.e. this:

```
AND        P.current_policy NOT IN (SELECT PolicyNumber FROM @Bridge)
```

Will do the same as this, you don't need both.

```
AND        B.PolicyNumber != H.current_policy
```

2, It's worth a try to remove all that grouping from your sub query - you don't actually use `policimage_num` for anything. So why do the grouping? If you are worried that many rows are returned from Address, then you can use DISTINCT on your column set instead, that may be faster.

3, Is A.state_id a nullable value? If not consider trying an INNER JOIN to Address and removing the null check.

4, In all honesty I'm not seeing an obvious reason for that subquery at all, it seems to be over-complicating matters. Can you not simply join the tables together without it (again using DISTINCT if required)?

In other words get tweaking, I bet you can get it below the original run time if you try a few of these ideas.